In Excel, I have to do a calculation in each row of a document, then sum the result for all rows. I need to do this in one cell though. How?
I have a file which has multiple rows. In each row, I need to do a calculation. For example, in cell D1, I write:
=(B1-A1)*C1

I then need to sum all the rows of that result, say:
=sum(D1:D30)

Is there a way to do this in a single cell instead of doing the calculation in each row of column D and then summing all the individual results?
I do not know enough about Excel to have tried this yet. I only know how to do it by doing the calculation in each row and then summing.

In this case =SUM((B1:B30-A1:A30)*(C1:C30)) would work, but take a look at BYROW, BYCOL, MAP formulas

=SUM((B1:B30-A1:A30)*C1:C30) should work if you are using Excel 365 (as per the tag).
In later versions of excel you can use dynamic array formulas like this.
